# Security permission to only read SSAS Cube with Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, ssas, pivot

I have an SSAS database set up on a SQL Server 2008 server.  I have a Role set up with a group of users that I want to be able to access the Cubes in that database.  I set up "Read definition" and "Read Access" wheverever it says, but that didn't seem to work.

The users were able to open up a pivot table that I had previously set up, but none of the hours would show up, but the dimension data would show up just fine (users, departments, etc).

I then set up an individual user and gave them Full control (Admin), which worked just fine.  What am I missing that allows them to access the Cube properly?  Process database?  Something else?

Answer (score 6):

In order for a specific role to have permissions over a cube data you have to specifically grant cube permissions to that role.
That can be done using the Cube tab in the role properties page: in SSAS

-> Databases -> Your db -> Roles -> your specific role -> Cubes tab.

You can assign specific permissions for:

- Access - None, Read, or ReadWrite
- LocalCube/DrillthroughAccess - None, Drillthrough/Drillthrough and Local Cube
- Process

Same for dimensions and their data and specific cell data.
You can find further info about cube permissions in the following articles:

- [Permissions and Access Rights (Analysis Services - Multidimensional Data)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174786%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Configuring permissions for SQL Server Analysis Services](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2776/configuring-permissions-for-sql-server-analysis-services/)
- [Security with Analysis Services - Overview](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9600.security-with-analysis-services-overview.aspx)

Comment: I would also like to add that giving the user full control/admin is almost never a good idea even as a temporary fix.

Comment: Well..it might work for the moment on the dev's machine, when you're a bit lazy to check/fix privileges, but at some point in time you'll need to do it :-).